# How can I run mojolicious under Win32::Daemon?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm trying to run mojolicious as a Windows Service using Win32::Daemon, but I don't know how to return from the start callback after starting the mojo app. The mojo app begins to listen but the Windows Service Controller assumes the start failed because you never reach the return statement.

```
sub Callback_Start
{
    my( $Event, $Context ) = @_;

    app->start; # <-- code hangs here

    $Context->{last_state} = SERVICE_RUNNING;
    Win32::Daemon::State( SERVICE_RUNNING );
    return();
}
```

Is it possible to start the Mojo server in a non-blocking way?

Comment: How would you start it manually (not as a service)? My guess is this fails to start the webserver that runs your app.

Comment: Checked that, the webserver starts. Also when I start it as a service you can access the webapp through the web browser. The problem is the service controller thinks the service didn't finish the start process

Comment: Please note that "non-blocking" in the web context often means something else: That the serever handles connections in a non-blocking /  asynchronous fashion

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have finally done:

```
my $daemon = Mojo::Server::Daemon->new( app => app, listen => ['http://*:3000' ] );

$daemon->prepare_ioloop;

Win32::Daemon::StartService( \%context, 100 );

Win32::Daemon::RegisterCallbacks({
    start => \&_start,
    running => \&_running,
    stop  => \&_stop,
    pause => \&_pause,
    continue => \&_continue,
});

# ...

sub _running {

    my( $Event, $context ) = @_;

    if( SERVICE_RUNNING == Win32::Daemon::State() ) {

        $daemon->ioloop->one_tick;
    }    

}

sub _start {
    my ($event, $context ) = @_;

    $context->{last_state} = SERVICE_RUNNING;
    $context->{last_event} = $event;

    Win32::Daemon::State( SERVICE_RUNNING );
        return();
}

# ...
```

Calling the **one_tick** method repeteadly allows you to embed the Mojo server (see the [doc](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Web_server_embedding)). With the code above Windows will call the **_running** sub every 100 milliseconds (second **StartService** parameter).

Answer (score 0):

What if you'd for a process, run the web app in the child and in the parent let the service controller know everything's running fine. I'm curios about how you'd stop the service in this case :)